# Using strong typed Map

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble strong typing my `Map` objects with TypeScript 1.8.10.  Here is an excerpt from `core-js` defining the Map interface:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, index: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value?: V): Map<K, V>;
    size: number;
}
```

I want to create a map that uses string keys and only ever stores values with the shape `{name:string,price:number}`.  I tried declaring my object with:

```
let oMap:Map<string,{name:string,price:number}> = new Map();
```

However, the compiler throws error `TS2322: Type 'Map<{}, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, { name: string; price: number; }>'`. Is there a way to take advantage of strong typing when using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) `Map` objects in TypeScript?

Comment: I think it's better to define an interface for {name:string,price:number}

Comment: Typically i would do so. It wouldn't have helped me here: the error was triggered because there was no type on the right sign of the assignment (next to `new Map`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to provide generic types information to the created `Map` like this:

```
let oMap:Map<string,{name:string,price:number}> = new Map<string,{name:string,price:number}>();
```

And after that you can omit the type declaration, leaving the job to the compiler:

```
// oMap is correctly inferred to be Map<string,{name:string,price:number}>
let oMap = new Map<string,{name:string,price:number}>();
```