# How can I define an object based array in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

In Javascript, I can define a collection using an object, something like this:

```
var myArray = {};
myArray['some-key1'] = new CustomObject('param1');
myArray['some-key2'] = new CustomObject('param2');
myArray['some-key3'] = new CustomObject('param3');
```

In TypeScript, can I have a collection based on object's properties, like in Javascript?

Another question, if I have 100 elements in one collection, what would be faster - storing these items in a classic array (`myarray.push(instanceObj)`), or storing them as properties of objects?

Comment: Use Map class, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894517/typescript-map-how-to-use-strong-types

Comment: Another option is to have a object with subobjects.

Comment: `var myArray: {[key: string]: CustomObject} = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of keys, the best thing to do is:

```
const myObject = {
    "some-key1": new CustomObject("param1"),
    "some-key2": new CustomObject("param2"),
    "some-key3": new CustomObject("param3"),
}
```

Note that now even something like this typechecks:

```
myObject["some-key1"] // TypeScript correctly infers the type to be CustomObject!
```

If you can't do that, the best way is to use an index type:

```
let myObject: { [key: string]: CustomObject };
```

which indicates to TypeScript that myObject maps strings to CustomObjects.

> Another question, if I have 100 elements in one collection, what would be faster - storing these items in a classic array (myarray.push(instanceObj)), or storing them as properties of objects?

It really depends on what you're planning to do with the array/object. What's your use case?